# Hibernate - how to fetch @OneToMany lazy collection inside another @OneToMany lazy collection without N+1

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, lazy-initialization

I have something like this

```
Entity1
@Id
String id1;
@OneToMany(Fetch = LAZY)
List<Entity2> list1;
...

Entity2
@Id
String id2;
@OneToMany(Fetch = LAZY)
List<Entity3> list2;
...

Entity3
@Id
String id3;
...
```

I want to initialize list1 and list2 inside the same session.
I'm stuck at

```
entity1 = (Entity1) session
                    .createCriteria(Entity1.class)                    
                    .setFetchMode("list1", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .uniqueResult();
```

I can't think of a proper way to initialize also the second nested list of Entity2, without using Hibernate.initialize and cause N+1 queries or using EAGER.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the legacy Hibernate Criteria API. It's deprecated and was removed in Hibernate 6.

You can fetch the first collection with join fetching and the second one with `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` fetching, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Entity1.class)
public interface Entity1Dto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping(fetch = MULTISET)
    Set<Entity2Dto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Entity2.class)
    interface Entity2Dto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
        @Mapping(fetch = MULTISET)
        Set<Entity3Dto> getRoles();
    }
    @EntityView(Entity3.class)
    interface Entity3Dto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

`MULTISET` fetching will aggregate all child rows and hence avoid the N + 1 problem. Also see the [documentation](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#multiset-fetch-strategy) for more info on this.

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`Entity1Dto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, Entity1Dto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<Entity1Dto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!